# Caused by - java.io.FileNotFoundException - /testfolder/abc.txt (Is a directory)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

We have a spring boot app which reads a file and processes the data to be stored in DB. On my team mates machine when we try to execute the program we get the following error:
The error is thrown by this line: `BeanReader beanReader = factory.createReader("txt", file);`

```
2020-06-24 16:54:05.054  | INFO   | com.example.sample.processor.TextFileProcessorFactory | Start processing txt file abc.txt
2020-06-24 16:54:05.054  | ERROR  | com.example.sample.processor.TextFileProcessorFactory | File Processing has been completed with Error:
org.beanio.BeanReaderException: Failed to open file '/testfolder/abc.txt' for reading
                at org.beanio.StreamFactory.createReader(StreamFactory.java:81) ~[beanio-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
                at com.example.sample.processor.miniprocessor.FlatFileParser.getApprovedProductList(FlatFileParser.java:54) ~[main/:?]
                at com.example.sample.processor.TextFileProcessorFactory$1.processFile(TextFileProcessorFactory.java:96) ~[main/:?]
                at com.example.sample.processor.TextFileProcessorFactory$1.process(TextFileProcessorFactory.java:69) [main/:?]
                at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:452) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:219) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:183) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) [camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /testfolder/abc.txt (Is a directory)
                at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
                at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
                at org.beanio.StreamFactory.createReader(StreamFactory.java:76) ~[beanio-2.1.0.M1.jar:2.1.0.M1]
                ... 21 more
2020-06-24 16:54:05.054  | ERROR  | com.example.sample.processor.ErrorProcessor | An exception happened so we move file abc.txt to an error folder
2020-06-24 16:54:05.054  | INFO   | com.example.sample.routes.TextFileProcessingRoute | Complete moving the file to error folder /testfolder/error/24-06-2020
```

The app is running fine in my machine as well in our target servers. We both have same java versions and we are executing them on Mac.

Any ideas on why he is getting this error? When I tested a sample text file, its able to read the data as a file but if I place the actual file, it immediately errors out identifying the file as folder. Again on my machine everything is fine.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM <docker registory>/alpine-adoptopenjdk-jre:8

MAINTAINER <my team>

RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup

RUN mkdir -p /home/appuser/global/data/in/ \
    && mkdir -p /home/appuser/global/data/error/ \
    && mkdir -p /home/appuser/global/data/archive/ \
    && mkdir -p /home/appuser/global/data/testfiles/ \
    && mkdir -p /home/appuser/global/bin/ \
    && mkdir -p /home/appuser/global/config/

RUN chmod -R 777 /home/appuser \
    && chown -R appuser:appgroup /home/appuser

USER appuser

COPY build/libs/file_processing.jar /home/appuser/global/bin/file_processing.jar
ADD testfiles/testfile.txt /home/appuser/global/data/in/

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-XX:+UseParallelGC" , "-Xmx2048M", "-Dspring.profiles.active=local", "-jar", "/home/appuser/global/bin/file_processing.jar" ]
```

Comment: Since you're using Unix path, I would assume that there's a privilege error ... program cannot read the file ... check the rights over the file `ls -tla` or place the file into home folder, or use `chown` over the folder with the same user running the spring app.

Comment: I was able to replicate the same issue with a container. Since my app in the container executes as root and has full access, I still get the same error as above. any pointers?

Comment: change the file location to /home/<user>/file for example or chown the folder to the current user

Comment: I did chown the currentuser:group which I created in the dockerfile. still the same issue. the app in the container is running as currentuser. is it a problem with the beanio API which I am using or is it a problem with the way the app is running. When the app runs locally on my machine and on the servers, its fine. now I am trying to convert it to docker container (also a new team member is facing the same issue), the file is read and getting converted to a directory. I even created the directories under /home/<user> and modified the chown on these folders. still the same issue

Comment: If in docker a file becomes directory it means that you gave wrong --volume specification. Please share your Dockerfile because is really hard to debug something without viewing it.

Comment: @user1452962, I did add the Dockerfile in the post. Even if I comment the ADD statement in dockerfile and copy the file manually to running docker container, its the same error.

Comment: I would try moving the USER after copy and add, and also move the run chmod after the copy and add just before USER ... Also I would probably go with 775 as I don't really understand why you need so wide privileges when you anyway chown the whole folder.